# calling objects from other methods in java

Tags: java, testing

I am a novice programmer and was wondering how I can create a test method that calls the object from the setUp() method above. Is there a better way to do this where a method is used to initialize the objects and the test method does the testing??

Any tips are appreciated..

```
public class ProjectTeamRemoveMemberTest {
    
    //Initialize test object
    public static void setUp() {
        Date date = new Date();
        Employee e = new Employee("Alice", date);
        Project p = new Project();
    }

    @Test
    public void removeTeamMember_True_ifMemberIsSelected() {
        setUp();
        assertEquals(true, p.removeTeamMember(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create those variables on class level, assign values in setup and refere to them in a test.

```
public class ProjectTeamRemoveMemberTest {
    
    static Date date;
    static Employee e;
    static Project p;

    //Initialize test object
    public static void setUp() {
        date = new Date();
        e = new Employee("Alice", date);
        p = new Project();
    }

    @Test
    public void removeTeamMember_True_ifMemberIsSelected() {
        assertEquals(true, p.removeTeamMember(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see, i would have to make the variables on class level public static right? so they can be access from the setUp() method?

Comment: Since setUp method is static then yes, those variables have to be static as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Before` annotation or `@BeforeEach` (if you use JUnit5)

public class ProjectTeamRemoveMemberTest {

```
private Employee e;
private Project p;

@Before // will be called before each test mehod
public void createEmployee() {
   e = new Employee("Alice", new Date());
}
@Before 
public void createProject() {
   p = new Project();
}

@Test
public void removeTeamMember_True_ifMemberIsSelected() {
    assertEquals(true, p.removeTeamMember(e));
}
```

}